# Is it possible to detect if a HTTPRequest is available?

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Silverstripe Version: 4.2

I have a custom `AssetAdapter` that makes some changes to the filesystem based on the current request. I am using injector to get the request:

`$request = Injector::inst()->get(HTTPRequest::class);`

For the most part this works fine, but in a couple of isolated instances, I get the error:

```
ERROR [Emergency]: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest::__construct(), 0 passed and at least 2 expected
IN GET /ecms-client/public/markseen
Line 157 in /project/path/vendor/silverstripe/framework/src/Control/HTTPRequest.php
```

This appears to be an issue/conflict with GraphQL and Assets (GraphQL doesn't always seem to have the current request available). I was wondering if there was a way to check if the current HTTPRequest is available/setup before trying to get it via `Injector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, `Injector::inst()->get()` will create a new instance if one doesn't exist yet. Since `HTTPRequest` requires two arguments during construction, you will get errors.

You can check if one exists using `->has()`:

```php
if (Injector::inst()->has(HTTPRequest::class)) {
    $request = Injector::inst()->get(HTTPRequest::class);
    // do something
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD, this has been doing my head in! This solution works perfectly!